# Compare object to object from hash map in android

Tags: android, hashmap

I have `HashMap<Shop, String> shopMap` where I put two values:

```
shopMap(shopModel1, shopModel1.getName());
shopMap(shopModel2, shopModel2.getName());
```

In my method for search shop by name I passed object of shop identical like shopModel1 to get his name:

```
public String getNameForShop(Shop filter) {
        return shopMap.get(filter);
    }
```

but I get null. Objects have the same all values. There is any way to get shop name from hash map using object?

Comment: shopMap(shopModel1.getName(), shopModel1); try with reverse

Comment: where did you put data in shopMap?

Comment: It depends on your `equals()`/`hashCode()` implementation inside `Shop`. The simplest solution in your case is probably to just swap your key/value, so `getName()` is used as the key, although you certainly could use `Shop` as your key as well.

Comment: @Pravin your solution is great, thx!

Comment: @edi233 welcome bro !!!

Comment: @Parvin You are right man!

Answer (score 1):

It is not ok to have the object as key value. Map it by name.

I guess mapping by object, in fact, it happens with the object's memory address. Then you search in map for an object it doesn't compare objects fields, just the addresses.

```
HashMap<String, Shop> shopMap;
if( shopMap.get("shopname").equals(anotherShop) ){
    //do staff
}
```